# git repo was copied manually to server how can I diff the files against the repo after infection?

Tags: git, diff

One of the domains on our web server was hacked recently and I need to do a git diff against our repo. The problem is however that git was not installed on the server and I believe the repo was pushed using ssh.

Git is now installed, is it possible to initialise git so that it now knows its origin? Or can I do a git diff against the repo?

Your help is appreciated as always :)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible:

1. Convert your folder to a git working copy:

   ```
   cd /path/to/working-to-be-copy/ # replace with actual path
   git init
   git remote add origin url-to-git-remote # replace with actual url
   git fetch
   ```
2. Make git think that this working copy had this particular commit checked out:

   ```
   git reset --mixed origin/master # or whatever branch/commit you want to diff against
   ```
3. Inspect the results:

   show overall situation, including ignored files (keep in mind: if `.gitignore` was changed, git will use working copy version):

   ```
   git status --ignored
   ```

   show the diff between selected commit and actual files (does not include untracked/ignored files, though):

   ```
   git diff
   ```